# Malloc won't sort more than 8 inputs

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

My program takes 3 lines of input. The first line being whether you want to sort it by odd or even, the second line being how large your array is and the third line being the integers in the array. It works until you use an array larger than 8. I believe it's to do with malloc but I've tried to debug this code for a couple of hours now and I can't fix this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* sort;
int n;
int* ar;
int i;

int test()

{
    int temp;
    int j = 1;

    //printf("%s", sort);

    if (strcmp(sort, "odd") == 0) {

        for (i = 0; i < n;) {

            if (j != n) {

                if (ar[i] % 2 != 0) {

                    if (ar[j] % 2 != 0) {

                        if (ar[j] < ar[i]) {

                            temp = ar[i];
                            ar[i] = ar[j];
                            ar[j] = temp;
                            j++;
                        }
                        else {
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        j++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    j++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else {

                i++;
                j = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(sort, "even") == 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            if (j != n) {

                if (ar[i] % 2 == 0) {

                    if (ar[j] % 2 == 0) {

                        if (ar[j] < ar[i]) {

                            temp = ar[i];
                            ar[i] = ar[j];
                            ar[j] = temp;
                            j++;
                        }
                        else {
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        j++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    j++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else {

                i++;
                j = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void main()
{

    ar = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    sort = malloc(sizeof(char) + 1);

    printf("Enter odd or even\n");
    scanf("%s", sort);

   // printf("please input odd or even\n");

    printf("Enter the size of the array \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //printf("%s", sort);

    printf("Enter the elements of the array \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
    }

    test();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        printf("%d ", ar[i]);
    }

    // return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc` won't sort anything.

Comment: `ar = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);`  but `n` is `0`, and you are lucky that `n` is `0`....

Comment: Also `int test()` but `test` doesn't `return` anything

Comment: Moreover sort should have room for `5` chars to store `"even"`

Answer (score 2):

Code is typically executed in a linear fashion, but you don't seem to be doing that. You're allocating `ar` using `n`, but don't have a value for `n` yet until several lines later...

```
ar = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
sort = malloc(sizeof(char) + 1);

printf("Enter odd or even\n");
scanf("%s", sort);

// printf("please input odd or even\n");

printf("Enter the size of the array \n");
scanf("%d", &n);
```

You're also not allocating the size of `sort` big enough to contain any string longer than 1 character.